# Understanding the intros keyword work in Coq

Tags: coq, gallina

```
Theorem law_of_contradiction : forall (P Q : Prop),
  P /\ ~P -> Q.
Proof.
  intros P Q P_and_not_P.
  destruct P_and_not_P as [P_holds not_P].
```

I'm trying to reaaaally understand the `intros` keyword. Let's say that we want to prove `P /\ ~P -> Q`. Ok, somehow `intros P Q` introduce `P` and `Q`. But what does it mean? Does it recognize the `P` and `Q` from the thing to be proven? What about `P_and_not_P`? What is it? Why for P and Q it uses the same name, but for `P_and_not_P` is is defining a name?

**UPDATE:**

It looks like it's matching term by term:

```
Theorem modus_tollens: forall (P Q : Prop),
  (P -> Q) -> ~Q -> ~P.
Proof.
intro P.
intro Q.
intro P_implies_Q.
intro not_q.
intro not_p.
```

gives

```
P Q ℙ
P_implies_Q P → Q
not_q ~ Q
not_p P
```

but why isn't `not_p` equal to `~P`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What `intro A` (equivalent to `intros A`) does: if you have a goal of the form `forall (P : _), ...`, it renames `P` to `A`, removes the `forall` from the beginning of the goal and puts an assumption `A` into the goal.

```
(* Starting goal *)

-----------
forall P Q : Prop, P /\ ~P -> Q

(* Goal after [intros A] *)

A : Prop
------------
forall Q, A /\ ~A -> Q
```

If you do `intros P Q`, by picking the names already in the goal, no renaming is necessary so there is no change in names.

The other cases of `intros` you mention are special cases of that one behavior.

**Implications** in Coq are quantifications where the assumption is not named: `P /\ ~ P -> Q` is equivalent to `forall (H : P /\ ~P), Q`, noting that `H` is not used in the body `Q`. Hence, when you do `intros P_and_not_P`, you are renaming `H`, which is not used so you don't see a change in the goal. You can disable pretty printing to see that.

```
Unset Printing Notations.
```

```
(* Starting goal; a name that is not used becomes "_" *)

----------
forall (P Q : Prop) (_ : and P (not P)), Q.

(* After [intros P Q R] *)

P : Prop
Q : Prop
R : and P (not P)
----------
Q
```

The **negation** of `P`, denoted `~P`, is defined as `P -> False` in Coq (this is typical in intuitionistic logic, other logics might differ). You can see that in action with the tactic `unfold not`

```
(* Starting goal *)

----------
forall (P Q : Prop), (P -> Q) -> ~Q -> ~P.


(* After [unfold not] *)

----------
forall (P Q : Prop), (P -> Q) -> (Q -> False) -> P -> False.


(* After [intros P Q R S T] *)

P : Prop
Q : Prop
R : P -> Q
S : Q -> False
T : P
----------
False
```